# Correct way to use the signal closeEditor in QStyledItemDelegate?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am overriding the QStyledItemDelegate class and reimplementing the eventFilter function so I can customize the editor behavior when a Tab press is detected. However, the following is not working. What is the correct way to invoke the closeEditor signal?

```
class CustomDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def eventFilter(self, editor, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and
            event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab):
            print "Tab captured in editor"
            self.commitData.emit(editor) #This is working
            self.closeEditor.emit(editor) #This does not seem to do anything??
            return True
        return QStyledItemDelegate.eventFilter(self,editor,event)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I just ran into the same issue and found this question.

I solved it by changing the

`self.closeEditor.emit(editor)`

line to

`self.closeEditor.emit(editor, QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)`.

The `commitData` call will `setModelData`. If you don't call `closeEditor`, `setModelData` will be called again as the editor itself will close.